# Adding a column to model results in RangeError [Refactoring]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, rails-activerecord

I'm currently working on a assignment for ruby on rails course I'm doing. I have to refactor a blog app written in Rails and add the functionality to merge articles.

What I did was to add a new text field in the form that is displayed when you edit the article

```
<%= text_field 'article', 'merge' %>
```

After I do that, it complains that there is no `merge` method in article model so I went ahead and implemented that.

I run the following migration:

```
class AddMergeWithToContents < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :contents, :merge_with, :integer
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :contents, :merge_with
  end
end
```

Then, when when accessing again the app it gives me the following error:

```
 RangeError in Admin::SettingsController#update_database

bignum too big to convert into `long'

Rails.root: /home/saasbook/typo
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

app/controllers/admin/settings_controller.rb:38:in `[]'
app/controllers/admin/settings_controller.rb:38:in `update_database'
```

Full Trace

```
app/controllers/admin/settings_controller.rb:38:in `[]'
app/controllers/admin/settings_controller.rb:38:in `update_database'
actionpack (3.0.17) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (3.0.17) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:150:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.0.17) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:11:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.0.17) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.0.17) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:457:in `block in _run__331447277__process_action__533401003__callbacks'
activesupport (3.0.17) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:221:in `block in _conditional_callback_around_20300'
activesupport (3.0.17) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:331:in `around'
activesupport (3.0.17) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:315:in `_callback_around_20297'
activesupport (3.0.17) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:220:in `_conditional_callback_around_20300'
activesupport (3.0.17) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:456:in `_run__331447277__process_action__533401003__callbacks'
activesupport (3.0.17) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:410:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (3.0.17) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:94:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.0.17) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.0.17) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.0.17) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.0.17) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.0.17) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.0.17) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.0.17) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.0.17) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:119:in `process'
actionpack (3.0.17) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:41:in `process'
actionpack (3.0.17) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:138:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.0.17) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.0.17) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:178:in `block in action'
actionpack (3.0.17) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:68:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.17) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:68:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.0.17) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:33:in `call'
rack-mount (0.6.14) lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:148:in `block in call'
rack-mount (0.6.14) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:93:in `block in recognize'
rack-mount (0.6.14) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:75:in `optimized_each'
rack-mount (0.6.14) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:92:in `recognize'
rack-mount (0.6.14) lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:139:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.17) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:499:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.17) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.17) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.2.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.17) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.17) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:182:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.17) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:149:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.17) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:302:in `call'
activerecord (3.0.17) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:32:in `block in call'
activerecord (3.0.17) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:28:in `cache'
activerecord (3.0.17) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:12:in `cache'
activerecord (3.0.17) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:31:in `call'
activerecord (3.0.17) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:354:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.17) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:46:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.0.17) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:416:in `_run_call_callbacks'
actionpack (3.0.17) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:44:in `call'
rack (1.2.5) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:106:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.17) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:48:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.17) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:47:in `call'
railties (3.0.17) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:13:in `call'
rack (1.2.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.0.17) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.2.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:13:in `block in call'
<internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
rack (1.2.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.17) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:30:in `call'
railties (3.0.17) lib/rails/application.rb:168:in `call'
railties (3.0.17) lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
railties (3.0.17) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.2.5) lib/rack/content_length.rb:13:in `call'
rack (1.2.5) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:52:in `service'
/home/saasbook/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/home/saasbook/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/home/saasbook/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

This is the settings controller

```
class Admin::SettingsController < Admin::BaseController
  cache_sweeper :blog_sweeper

  def index
    if this_blog.base_url.blank?
      this_blog.base_url = blog_base_url
    end
    load_settings
  end

  def write; load_settings end
  def feedback; load_settings end
  def errors; load_settings; end

  def redirect
    flash[:notice] = _("Please review and save the settings before continuing")
    redirect_to :action => "index"
  end

  def update
    if request.post?
      Blog.transaction do
        params[:setting].each { |k,v| this_blog.send("#{k.to_s}=", v) }
        this_blog.save
        flash[:notice] = _('config updated.')
      end

      redirect_to :action => params[:from]
    end
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
    render params[:from]
  end

  def update_database
    @current_version = Migrator.current_schema_version
    @needed_version = Migrator.max_schema_version
    @support = Migrator.db_supports_migrations?
    @needed_migrations = Migrator.available_migrations[@current_version..@needed_version].collect do |mig|
      mig.scan(/\d+\_([\w_]+)\.rb$/).flatten.first.humanize
    end
  end

  def migrate
    if request.post?
      Migrator.migrate
      redirect_to :action => 'update_database'
    end
  end

  private
  def load_settings
    @setting = this_blog
  end
end
```

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you show you whole form code? Because your text_field code is wrong. It must either be `<%= f.text_field 'merge' %>` (where f is the variable defined in the `form_for` tag) or `<%= text_field_tag 'article', 'merge' %>`

Comment: Sure, here is the link in pastebin: http://pastebin.com/LqESPBXm
Method form_tag appeared to have been used. Thank you

Comment: I'm not understanding this merge method. You want it in the article model yet you add a :merge_with column to the "contents" table. How are "contents" and "articles" related? What does merging look like?

Comment: Contents is the table associated with the article model. merge is supposed to be an integer that you get from the form and that represents the id of the particular article you want to merge the article with.

Comment: Can you edit your post to include your settings controller?

Comment: Sure, I just edited.

Comment: Looks like the error is in `@needed_migrations = Migrator.available_migrations[@current_version..@needed_version].collect do |mig|`. So either @current_version or @needed_version is WAY too big. Not sure if you can check those. What is the file name for your new migration?

Comment: Maybe I'm not supposed to run any migration ? I actually don't need to store that information in the model, I'm just doing it because Rails asked me to when I used <%= text_field 'article', 'merge' %>. Is there another function I could use so that I can access that information from the url and not necesirely storing it in the model ?

Comment: If you don't need to store that in the database, then don't. You can pass a url param through a link like `<%= link_to "Merge Articles", merge_articles_path(article_id: @article.id) %>`. Of course, I don't know what path you have or what variable you would call it but that can get you going. Let me know if this works.

Comment: I need to pass it through a form.

Comment: You can change the `text_field` to `text_field_tag`, removing the first argument `article`. Or you can add a method to your article model named `merge=(val)` in which you can do whatever you need to.

Comment: No problem. Just posted an answer to just wrap it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So to just answer the question, you can change the `text_field` to `text_field_tag` and remove the first argument. Or you can add a "setter" method to your article model named `merge=(val)` in which you can code whatever you need to. Hope this helps!